# Correct way to separate data and domain layers with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the correct way to separate the domain and data layers when using Entity Framework?

My example below is clearly wrong because the data layer is fetching and transforming ALL ThingEntities from the repository before applying the IsRelevant logic.

However, I can't see how to get the repository to filter the ThingEntities without putting domain logic into the data layer.

What's the correct approach here?  Thanks.

```
namespace DomainLayer
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public int Id;
        public Thing(int id) { Id = id; }
        public bool IsRelevant()
        {
            return Id%2 == 0;  // or some domain-specific logic
        }
    }

    public interface IThingRepo
    {
        List<Thing> Things { get; }
    }

    public class ThingManager
    {
        private readonly IThingRepo _thingRepo;
        public ThingManager(IThingRepo thingRepo)
        {
            _thingRepo = thingRepo;
        }
        public List<Thing> RelevantThings()
        {
            return _thingRepo.Things.Where(x => x.IsRelevant()).ToList();
        } 
    }
}

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class EfDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual IDbSet<ThingEntity> ThingEntities { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThingEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThingEntityMapper
    {
        public static Thing Transform(ThingEntity thingEntity)
        {
            return new Thing(thingEntity.Id);
        }
    }

    public class ThingRepo : IThingRepo
    {
        private readonly EfDbContext _context;
        public ThingRepo(EfDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public List<Thing> Things
        {
            get
            {
                var result = Enumerable.Empty<Thing>();
                foreach (var thingEntity in _context.ThingEntities)
                {
                    result = result.Concat(new[] {ThingEntityMapper.Transform(thingEntity)});
                }
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do use extension methods for this purpose...

Comment: Consider having `thingRepo` return an `IQueryable` for `_thingRepo.Things` -- this should get you headed in the proper direction.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework pretty much can be seen as a public API over the marriage and simplification of the domain and data access layers, so if you want a distinct separation you generally end up writing superfluous code to encapsulate everything behind a repository or domain layer (which is quickly falling out of fashion).

My suggestion is to make your peace with what appears to be a violation of separation of concerns and take advantage of calling the context directly from your business logic at first. Then if you see a reason to abstract it behind a separate layer, let that happen organically instead of defining a line of demarcation between your layers from the beginning. You'll save yourself a lot of time agonizing over whether or not "the rules" are being followed.

I prefer to think of it this way: If I had engineered EF from the beginning, would I have as much problem with consuming the context in my code? Probably not, because I'd view the code I'd written as creating a layer between the DAL and my higher-level logic.

Overall, my opinion is that the general source of discomfort for devs comes from not being in charge of designing the code that the context and table abstractions provide. If you were, you might view the problem differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a correct way - but there are certainly some things I would change from your example.

The domain layer should know about the data layer and not vice-versa. This means your mapper should be in the domain layer. Also, I would keep the data layer as small as possible and get rid of the repository - I don't see the point of using a repository with EF.

Although most people seem to, I wouldn't mix objects holding state with business logic. In other words `IsRelevent()` should not be in `Thing`.

Consider renaming `ThingManager` to something more specific to avoid violating separation of concerns. I'm leaving the name in my example as I don't know what it will do and therefore what it will be called.

As long as you return `IQueryable` you can separate your queries into separate internal methods and then have your public method put them all together. This way you can reuse queries such as `IsRelevent()` but only publicly expose the higher level more business specific queries.

So your data layer would be something like

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    public class EfDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual IDbSet<ThingEntity> ThingEntities { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThingEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and your domain layer

```
namespace DomainLayer
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public int Id;
    }

    internal class ThingEntityMapper
    {
        public static Thing Transform(ThingEntity thingEntity)
        {
            return new Thing{ Id = thingEntity.Id };
        }
    }

    internal interface IThingQueries
    {
        IQueryable<ThingEntity> FilterRelevent(IQueryable<ThingEntity> things);
    }

    internal class ThingQueries : IThingQueries
    {
        public IQueryable<ThingEntity> FilterRelevent(IQueryable<ThingEntity> things)
        {
            return things.Where(x => x.Id%2 == 0);
        }
    }

    public class ThingManager
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private readonly IThingQueries _queries;
        public ThingManager(DbContext _context, IThingQueries queries)
        {
            _context = context;
            _queries = queries;
        }
        public List<Thing> RelevantThings()
        {
            return _queries
                   .FilterRelevent(_context.ThingEntities)
                   .Select(ThingEntityMapper.Transform)
                   .ToList();
        } 
    }
}
```

This may contain errors which stop it building as it is just intended to indicate a general architecture where your data layer is just intended to hold the entities and context and the domain layer to do the rest.